# Why is remove from role members not working?

Tags: powershell, ssas

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.rolemembercollection.remove?view=analysisservices-dotnet

For some reason, this is not working properly. I keep reconnecting the server and checking if the ID gets removed and its not!

```
$ssasInstance = "<ssas instance name>"
$accountName= "<domain\user>"
Import-Module SqlServer
[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server]$SSASserver = New-Object ([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server])
$SSASserver.Connect($ssasInstance) 
$role= $SSASserver.Roles["Administrators"]
$role.Members.Remove($accountName)
$role.Update()
```

there is no errors or anything. i did a conditional statement to check if ID exists, and if it does, remove and output removed!

i do get output

> removed ID!

but the ID is not really getting removed!

I have tried ADD, so that i know nothing is wrong with the script, and add works! only remove for some reason is not working...

Comment: How do you check it wasn't removed? Did you check your server logs for any errors?

Comment: @Seth no I directly check the server properties, where you can add/remove users manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the threads are somewhat related, in case someone searches for a similar title in the future, here is the answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55145118/8397835