# How to use Remove-LocalGroupMember to remove from a server?

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that is supposed to remove members from a server:

```
$ssasInstance = ""
$accountName= ""
Import-Module SqlServer
[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server]$SSASserver = New-Object ([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server])
$SSASserver.Connect($ssasInstance) 
$role= $SSASserver.Roles["Administrators"]
$role.Members.Remove($accountName)
$role.Update()
```

The problem is for some reason Remove() is not really working, no errors generated, but it doesnt remove the user.

I tested the script by instead adding a user, `$role.Members.Add($accountName)` and this works great! so i know that it must be a bug with the `remove()` method, and the only option I have is to use `Remove-LocalGroupMember`

I tried just using it like this:

```
$ssasInstance = ""
$accountName= ""
Import-Module SqlServer
[Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server]$SSASserver = New-Object ([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Server])
$SSASserver.Connect($ssasInstance) 
$role= $SSASserver.Roles["Administrators"]
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group "Administrators" -Member "$accountName"
$role.Update()
```

but that doesnt work either...although i think its because it doesnt know exactly where its removing from...

I tried this too, but to no avail:

```
Remove-LocalGroupMember -Group "$role" -Member "$accountName"
```

So how can i integrate this module into my script?

Comment: `Remove-LocalGroupMember` removes members from the local *Windows* administrator group, which is not at all the same as the Analysis Services administrators. You're likely running into the issue that the `.Remove` method only removes exact *object instances*, not members by name (using strings passes through a conversion that uses the `RoleMember` constructor that takes one string). Try `$role.Members.Remove($role.Members.Where{$_.Name -eq $accountName}[0])`. (And yes, that you need this syntax is fairly bizarre, but SMO wasn't designed to integrate smoothly into PowerShell.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert OMG!!! you sir, are a life savior!!! :D FINALLY!!!!! do you want to post it as an answer? you deserve the credit for this! i have posted on serveral forums and no one was able to figure this out! finally after 2 days!! you saved me soo much more time :D

Comment: @JeroenMostert also, suppose i am already having an if statement check if the member exists, would i still need this? Where{$_.Name -eq $accountName ? and if not, would it be just $role.Members.Remove($role.Members[0])

Comment: No -- `$role.Members[0]` is always the first member in the role, and that need not be the one matching the account name you're after. The `Where` is not intended to check anything, but to *find* the member whose name we know.

Comment: @JeroenMostert i see! can you tell me how come the add method doesnt require this cimplicated bizzare code that remove does? are the constructors different?

Comment: I'm working on the answer now. Yes, it's a bizarre situation, caused by the SMO designers not anticipating the use cases very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate confluence of circumstances: when you do

```
$role.Members.Add("member")
```

This works because, under water, the string `"member"` is implicitly converted by PowerShell to a `RoleMember` with a `Name` of `member` and an empty `Sid`. All fine. However, if you then do

```
$role.Members.Remove("member")
```

Nothing happens, because you will create a *new* `RoleMember` instance, and since `RoleMember` has no implementation of `.Equals()` (a fairly bizarre oversight), different instances will never be considered the same.

This means you can *only* remove members by getting the actual instance in the collection (or by index, I suppose):

```
$member = $role.Members.Where{$_.Name -eq "member"} | Select -First 1
$role.Members.Remove($member)
```

Note that you will not get an error if there is no such member (because `Remove` allows `$null`, again in a rather bizarre oversight), so you may want to check for `$member -eq $null` if you want to verify that.

Definitely do not use `Remove-LocalGroupMember` -- that cmdlet is part of a [completely different module](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/remove-localgroupmember) and removes members from local Windows groups, not SSAS roles.

Comment: thank you! can you post the answer here as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112876/why-is-remove-from-role-members-not-working I am not sure how i can create a related link on that thread. also, i think the questions here are different, so i dont think the other thread should be deleted.

Comment: That's basically the same question. I could be flagged as a duplicate of this one, but even as a duplicate it adds no additional value since it uses essentially the same wording. You should delete it (and maybe give this one the title of the old one, since the title is definitely better).